# integrating a discourse message board with an existing rails site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, discourse

I'm looking at integrating a message board for a site I'm developing in rails. The new discourse board looks interesting http://www.discourse.org/ but there isn't much information about integrating into another site either via oauth2 or sso or perhaps using a rails engine type system. Has anyone succesfully set this up with an app like this?

thx

**edit t**
Is there a roadmap for how this integration could take place in the future? Parts of it look really intriguing but would like some more info on how this use case could be handled.

**edit 2**
Since this question is getting a fair amout of traffic, I want to add this post http://meta.discourse.org/t/integrating-discourse-with-current-user-database/6669 which goes over the SSO attempts going on at discourse currently. I have also been in contact with the people at thougtbot about their implementation.

Comment: It does not appear to be on their roadmap right now, although I'm sure it's something they would like to implement. Discourse is in pre beta right now so it's lacking features and polish. If you got the time you could always implement it yourself ;-)

Comment: I would also like to second this feature being added.  I'm not sure why it's not more important.  I think most of the time, or at least a lot of times forums don't stand on their own, they are integrated into other sites and need to somehow work with the main applications authentication system.

Comment: I'd have to agree. Having some kind of unified authentication system or at least having the project as a mountable rails engine is crucial (I think) for most people with existing apps out there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was interested in the same issue but here's what I found on [Github issues](https://github.com/discourse/discourse/issues/244):

> The easiest way to get it running would be to install Discourse
>   outside of your app. We do offer the full source code if you want to
>   integrate with your existing login system, but I imagine it would be a
>   fair amount of work at this point.
>
> Right now we haven't focused much on production deployments since
>   we're pre-beta and want to make sure people have a super easy upgrade
>   system in place to stay on top of security holes.

Comment: thx Mike, that seems about as close as there will be until someone goes about hacking apart their User model. Really wish there was a way to use this as a Rails engine or via a SSO mechanim which would seem to be the killer use case.

Comment: as a heads up, thoughtbot has made an oauth plugin that they are probably going to open source

Answer (score -3):

Not done any app with Discourse, but if their site does not provide a lot of info did you browse the Git Repository https://github.com/discourse/discourse it provides plenty of information and resources links like these ones :

1. **Discourse Developer Install Guide** (Vagrant) :
   https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/master/docs/VAGRANT.md
2. **Developer Advanced** :
   https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/master/docs/DEVELOPER-ADVANCED.md
3. **Admin quick Start** : https://github.com/discourse/discourse/wiki/The-Discourse-Admin-Quick-Start-Guide

Hope it can be of some help for you

Cheers

Comment: thx for reply - most of that is pretty far from the question I'm asking here (unless I missed something). 3 more days though and you could be collecting bounty. Even if a discussion of how it could be implemented in the future.