# Integrating a Discourse forum with a Devise rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, discourse

So I'm looking to integrate a Discourse forum with the same authentication as the main app (Devise). It would be mainapp.com and forum.mainapp.com. A lot like [codeschool](http://discuss.codeschool.com) and [hummingbird](http://forums.hummingbird.me/) has going.

I saw [another SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393808/integrating-a-discourse-message-board-with-an-existing-rails-site) that was asked a year ago and wondering if there have been any improvments/ideas on doing this.

A user would sign up at mainapp.com and be automatically signed in to forum.mainapp.com using their devise user details to fill discourse user fields.

As a fairly new ruby/rails developer It's a bit hard wrapping my head around what to do, although I suspect it starts at carrying a session cookie over from mainapp.com to forum.mainapp.com.

Wondering if this has become easier to do over the past year and if anyone can steer me in the right direction for implementing this.

Answer (score 2):

Discourse now supports Single Sign On to integrate Discourse users with the main website now. Official documentation here:

https://meta.discourse.org/t/official-single-sign-on-for-discourse/13045

Comment: First of all which url to hit from our existing rails app so that payload can be sent?

Comment: You should explore the documents and the discourse source code. Shouldn't be too difficult to find out.